# Visual Studio Error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directory

I was trying to run my first C++ code in Visual Studio, by creating a blank project and then creating a C++ source file in the project.

But, when I try to run, it just gives this error message.

[image]

When I go and look in the folder, I see that another folder with the same name has been created, and there is the file, but that is not the right directory.

[image]

[image]

This is my code, by the way:

```cpp
#import <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the EXACT steps you took to create the project and the source file? Can you reproduce it again with a new project?

Comment: [For many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301), please provide text as text. About the only time you want to show an image is when you have a configuration panel you want to show (A picture literally worth a thousand words) to demonstrate how things have been set up or if you are asking about computer graphics.

Comment: *by creating a blank project* -- Did you actually create a Win32 Console project?  If not, that is what you should have used.

Comment: `#import <iostream>` I haven't played with modules yet, but they are very new. You may have to ask for them specifically or demand compatibility with a more recent C++ Standard revision. Or perhaps you meant `#include<iostream>`? Check Visual Studio's output tab for compiler errors and paste them into the question if necessary.

Comment: I clicked on "create a new project" then "empty project" and finally I went on "file" in the top left and clicked on "new" and then "visual c++ " and finally "C++ File (.cpp)

PS. I did mean #include sorry I am used to python

Comment: Why is "Project.exe" listed as a "Recipe" file and not an "Application"? Can you turn off the "Hide extensions for known types" option in the File Explorer.

Comment: I have no idea, I thought it was supposed to be an .exe file

Comment: Assuming you did not have 400+ errors I expect your problem is your antivirus. If you did have 400+ errors then your problem is your current SDK is not installed and you need to select an installed SDK in your settings. You should see information in the Visual Studio Output tab about the errors if you do have them,

Comment: After replacing `import` with `include` do you have the same problem?, if yes, check the Output tab for build errors an add the first 3-5 of the diagnostic messages to the question. We'll let you know if we need to see more. If there are no diagnostics and still no program, @drescherjm 's probably right about Antivirus.

Comment: In my output tab there seems to be nothing wrong.
I think there are no problems and my only antivirus is windows defender. Also if instead of creating an empty project I create a console project (like the one that has hello world on it) it works.

Comment: You don't need to provide a screenshot of your entire desktop to convey the fact that a file exists.  Just provide the path to the file in text format.  We'll believe you without the picture.

Comment: Guys, I think I fixed it... I don't really know how I was watching the video of this guy and I followed what he did. Basically, instead of creating the new file from the top left I right clicked on source files, then cliccked add and it worked. IDK why.